# android database through SQLIteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to learn the SQL Database stuff for SQLite using the android. I have seen a couple examples of the Queries....

I have a two part question about sqlite queries in android.

**Part 1**

Say I want to delete something. and I use the following Query.

```
db.delete(MY_DB_TABLE, "CustomerName = ?", new String[] { customerName });
```

what would happen if the Customer name had a bad character in it.

For example. If I use the following Query

```
db.execSQL("delete from " + MY_DB_TABLE + 
           " where customername = '" + customerName + "';");
```

and say for this example the name of my customer was "Arby's".

That query would blow up because the ' is a special character and the query would not be formatted correctly.

**Part 2**

does this format allow me to specify as many paramaters as I want.

Example:

```
db.delete(MYTABLE, "val1 = ? and val2 != ?", new String[] { "test", "test2" } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my post here:

[Storing Lists to A Database, and Retrieving Them All Together : Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520175/storing-lists-to-a-database-and-retrieving-them-all-together-android/5520241#5520241)

and short answer to your question, **yes**.

Each '?' means that an argument will be expected, so for each '?' you **WILL** have an exact number of arguments to pass in unless you want an exception :) !

Comment: do you know if the database object safe types the items. omitting out improper sql with safe values for the result. or is that my responsibility as the programmer.

Comment: It's your job to capture exceptions and handle them as best as you can. It will throw an exception if its not what it expects.