# Send image from Android client to AppEngine Cloud Endpoint

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, post, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing an Android applicaiton with AppEngine backend. I am creating the server part with Google Cloud Endpoints in Java. My problem is that I cannot send a Bitmap from the client to the server.

I used the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000114/how-to-send-image-data-to-server-from-android) but even if the client part does not seem to have any problems at all, the server part does not receive the data at all. I also think this solution might be a bit complicated and that it might work a different, easier way, however this is my first time implementing a server and first time sending a picture to it so I accept any good tips on this. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
        String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.
        String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://path_to_my_app/_ah/api/registration/v1/uploadImage").openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true); // true = autoFlush, important!

            // Send text file.
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textFile\"; filename=\"" + somename + "\"").append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
            writer.append(CRLF).flush();
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray), charset));
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    writer.append(line).append(CRLF);
                }
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
            }
            writer.flush();


//            End of multipart/form-data.
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

The server part:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "uploadImage", httpMethod = "POST")
public void uploadImage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload();
    try
    {
        FileItemIterator iterator = fileUpload.getItemIterator(request);

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            FileItemStream itemStream = iterator.next();

            String fieldName = itemStream.getFieldName();
            log.info("field name:"+fieldName);

            InputStream stream = itemStream.openStream();

            String result = getStringFromInputStream(stream);
            log.info("result: "+result);

            stream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileUploadException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

I am getting 204 no Content type now.

Comment: Convert image into base64 string and store it on server. it will work.

Comment: Look at the example you gave. The Content-Type cannot be 'text/plain' for an image which is a binary file.

Comment: what should I put there then? I tried multipart/form data. I guess the problem might also be in the server method argument data type

Comment: So I changed it to the multipart content type and I have updated the my question on the very bottom. I just dont know how to get the image on the server side now.

Answer (score 3):

I did it!

I think this is not the best way of doing it but it´s working so I am fine until I get a better solution.

So I take the Bitmap image and convert it to String:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
byte[] bitmapByte = outputStream.toByteArray();
String stringEncodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bitmapByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then I create a httpPostRequest and set a JsonObject to it with the image converted to String in it.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://my_app_path/_ah/api/registration/v1/uploadImage");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("image",stringEncodedImage);

StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

On the server side, in my Endpoint, I do this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "uploadImage", httpMethod = "POST")
public JSONObject uploadImage(JSONObject request) throws IOException
{
    String imageInString = (String) request.get("image");
    Blob blob = new Blob(imageInString.getBytes());
    ....save blob and do whatever you want...
}
```

The same goes the other way. I pack Blob into JsonObject and send it over.