# How to use Google Cloud to send binary files between Android devices?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-messaging

I want to build a messenger in Android to send binary files, i.e. "user A" sends "file 1" to "user B". At first I wanted to use Google Cloud Messenger, but it only works with text and is not meant to be used for files transfer. Is there a similar cloud service from Google to send also binary files?

Comment: You can use the blobstore to upload the file then share the link to user b. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

Comment: I saw this solution before. Is using blobstore a legitimate way of using the GAE/GCM APIs?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000114/how-to-send-image-data-to-server-from-android

Answer (score 0):

If the binary files are small, you could maybe send them over the Endpoints service, with a message containing a ByteField field. You'd have to encode it using a base64encode before sending it, and decode it the same way.

If the binary files are bigger, you should probably follow Ryan B's advice and make user A upload it to the blobstore, then send the blobstore link to userB for him to download it.

In both cases, the app engine server would merely act as a "mirror".

You could also give the XMPP implementation of google cloud a look, there's maybe something in there about uploading and downloading binary files.